# Integration-Test Phase Missing in Java 12

Tags: java, maven, java-12

I was tasked to update a project with Maven 3.0 / Java 8 to Maven 3.6 / Java 12. To my best knowledge I did just that, changing all kinds of dependencies. Now when running the build the `integration-test` phase seems to be missing.

For example, the following plug-in is not called any longer during `clean verify`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>do-magic</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
            <!-- ... -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can easily search the build log for `do-magic`, so I can confirm it's called in Java 8 but not in Java 12 (even though there might be some other changes I'm not aware of right now).

The debug output is:

```
[DEBUG] Goal:          com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:maven-replacer-plugin:1.4.1:replace (do-magic)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- same as above-->
</configuration>
```

So there is no information on why it is not executed.

I tried calling the goal `integration-test` manually, still the plug-in is not called. There is no additional information either.

I have no idea where to look for the source of the problem. I wouldn't even know where to disable integration tests like this (except for maybe `maven.test.skip`, which removes the test module from the reactor altogether, so it's not that).

Can anybody shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that the `integration-test` phase is skipped, it's that suddenly `maven-surefire-plugin` decided it wants to execute the tests as well. That fails, because the  `pre-integration-test` phase is needed for the tests.

I have no idea why that suddenly happened, so here is a pseudo fix that disables Surefire again:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
            <!-- We run integration tests with failsafe! -->
            <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```